# Last column of table distorts query result

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I am creating the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
Case_Number VARCHAR(50) Primary Key,
Sex VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE ourCases (
Case_Number VARCHAR(50) Primary Key,
Rage VARCHAR(30),
Activity VARCHAR(30),
Fatal VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Area_Time (
Case_Number VARCHAR(50) Primary Key,
ourYear int,
ourTime VARCHAR(20),
Area VARCHAR(50)
);
```

And all my querys work, except for when I include the last column of each table, which would be "Area", "Fatal" and "Sex", as soon as I include those my Count equals 0, even though it shouldn't be since I can see it in the .csv sheet.

The query I use

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
area_time,
ourcases,
person
WHERE
area_time.Case_Number = ourcases.Case_Number
AND
area_time.Case_Number = person.Case_Number
AND
person.Case_Number = ourcases.Case_Number
AND
ourYear = 2016
AND
ourTime = "Afternoon"
AND
Area = "Florida";
```

And when I drop the "Area = "Florida"" part it works accordingly.
I tried those queries inside my Java app and the mySQL workbench, but neither works. I simply can't see anything wrong with the data. There has been no issues with the .csv import either. What am I missing?

Comment: did you try to add and identifier with those three fields like as follows.
`area_time.ourYear = 2016 AND area_time.ourTime = 'Afternoon'`
`AND area_time.Area = 'Florida'`

if it doesn't work can you try to dump the data of those three tables and comment it here.

Comment: Tried identifiers before, didn't help apparently. [Here is the data I use](https://mega.nz/#!Hp5XTbTQ!qU1h3wiRqllGo28I_siaiOGv67fbU355fMLMDWjF9e0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PTI I tried this and can't reproduce your error, do you have anyfurther examples?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    area_time.Area,
    ourcases.Fatal,
    person.Sex
FROM
    area_time,
    ourcases,
    person
WHERE
    area_time.Case_Number = ourcases.Case_Number
        AND area_time.Case_Number = person.Case_Number
        AND person.Case_Number = ourcases.Case_Number
        AND ourYear = 2016
        AND ourTime = 'Afternoon'
        AND Area = 'Florida';
```

And the results:

[image]

Pleased to have another go if I can reproduce the issue.

Regards,

James

Comment: First of thanks for taking the time to try this out. Copied your exact query, but as a result I get nothing. [Here's a picutre.](http://imgur.com/a/5eQMR)

Comment: No worries, am clutching at straws a bit here but could character encoding have changed the characters? What do the 'Florida' entries look like if you just do `SELECT *` and find the values manaually? Are they actually the same as you think they are when compared using `EXACT()`in Excel or similar?

Comment: Ah, now I didn't use the EXACT() function just yet, but when I copy the entries the result is not 'Florida', as I expect it to be but it is 'Florida\r'. It does the same for alle entries of "Sex", "Fatal" and "Area" ('Florida\r', 'No\r', 'Male\r'). And if I than adjust the query to search for 'Florida\r' it works acordingly. So tyvm! But why is that?

Comment: They're ASCII control characters (used to make early printers work properly etc), you need the TRIM function in MySQL, do an UPDATE on all columns applying the function to any problematic fields and everything should work fine. Am on my mobile at the moment, let me know if you need a full working example and I'll put it in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Charles, have reflected, if you can actually see the '\r' on the string in MySQL when looking at the results in workbench then what you have is the visible (escaped) version of the Linux line end character, so effectively due to some problem with the original data or the import into MySQL some fields end with backslash and r. Check your plain text data before it gets imported and if you can see the characters then the cause of the problem exists outside of MySQL and ideally needs to be solved at source. The workaround would be an UPDATE with an IF that checks for \r and removes it with LEFT